# Polymer 1.x: $key throws error when saving to Firebase

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer

I want to save a `firebase-document` to Firebase. But I encounter the following error.

error.log

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Firebase.push failed: first argument  contains an invalid key ($key) in property 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.items'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

Here is the relevant code.

my-element.html

```
<firebase-document id="document" ... ></firebase document>
...
save: function() {
  var doc = this.$.document;
  console.log('Saved', doc.data);
  return doc.save(this.itemsPath).then(function() {
    console.log('Saved:', doc);
    doc.reset();
  }.bind(this));
  return Promise.resolve();
},
```

The data object contains a key label containing the `$` character. But this is automatically introduced by Firebase, not a programming decision.

console.log

```
Saved: {
  $key: "foo" // This is the object key in Firebase
  ...
}
```

What edits can I make to save my data?

Comment: Per 43081j@[Slack site](https://polymer.slack.com/messages/general/): 
try pass $key as the 2nd argument, `save(path, doc.data.$key)` ... the `save(...)` method on firebase-document will call `push(...)` if a key isn't provided, otherwise it will set the value normally. but this does confuse me, you shouldn't need to call save really at all. why not just set the path? so firebase-document handles it